# Does async requests with limited number of concurrent requests generally run faster?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I was playing with async python code trying to improve its performance, and noticed that when I set a limit on number of simultaneously executing tasks via Semaphore, the code usually runs faster than if I don't set any limit and just allow it to make as many requests as it likes. I also noticed, that when I limit number of web requests I get connection errors less often. Is this a general case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async` functions let us run several tasks <s>in parallel</s> at the same time, but they don't spawn any new threads or new processes. They all run in the same, single thread of the Python interpreter. That is to say, the interpreter can only run as fast as a single core of your processor, and the tasks can only run as fast as the interpreter. (This is the meaning of "concurrent", as distinct from "parallel", where multiple physical processors are in use at the same time.)

That's why folks say that `async` is good for I/O, and nothing else. It doesn't add *computation* power, it only lets us do a lot of otherwise-blocking stuff like HTTP requests in parallel. It "recycles" that blocking time, which would otherwise just be idling on the CPU waiting for the network to respond, wasting that CPU time.

So by "recycling" the CPU time that would otherwise be wasted, more tasks increases requests/second, but only up to a point. Eventually, if you spawn too many tasks, then the interpreter and the processor it's running on spend more CPU time managing the tasks than actually waiting for some network response. Not to mention that remote servers have their own bottlenecks (nevermind anti-DDOS protection).

So, `async` doesn't change the fact that you only have so much speed in your single thread. Too many tasks will clog the interpreter, and too many requests to remote servers will cause them to get fussy with you (whether by bottleneck or by anti-DDOS measures). So yes, you do need to limit your maximum concurrency.

In my local tests with `trio` and `httpx`, I get around 400-500 requests/second with around 128-256 concurrent tasks. Using more tasks than that reduces my total requests/second while burning more CPU time -- the interpreter does more task-management than requesting, at that point.

(I could probably optimize my local code, save some task-management CPU time for my interpreter, and maybe if I did that I could get 600 or 800 requests/second, but frankly the remote server I talk to can't really handle more requests anyways, so optimizing my local CPU usage would be mostly a waste of time. Better to add new features instead.)

Comment: Thank you, so if I understood correctly the optimal number of concurrent requests is cpu dependent? Is there a tool, that will magically limit number of requests based on current cpu performance, or should I test it for the exact server my code will run on?

Comment: Yes, it's a balance between your CPU and the average latency of a request-response cycle. For example, if a request-response cycle has an average latency of 500ms, and you spend about 2ms of CPU time per task per request-response cycle, then the optimal concurrency is probably around 500/2 = 250. This is what I mean by "recycling" those 500ms of latency into useful CPU work. You don't need to test your server really, just test your own computer against, say, Google or something. (e.g. ping 8.8.8.8 for 10 seconds, count how many pings you crammed in, repeat with varying concurrencies.)

Comment: Just a small note: `asyncio` it's not really parallelism (as you described in the 1st sentence of your answer), it's concurrency. Just some minor misunderstanding.

Comment: Ah, fair enough I suppose. Edited. At least in my head I don't much distinguish between the two, since abstractly speaking they have much in common as concerns humans writing multitasking code, whether by concurrency or parallelism in the strict senses (even tho I do certainly know the difference).